# Why does the fire freeze the inverted car?

Tags: tenet

In dialogue it's established that an uninverted fire freezes an inverted human.
Later an inverted car crashes. It's (inverted) gas flows on the street. And it is ignited by an inverted man with an inverted lighter. So shouldn't this be an inverted fire that burns the inverted car instead of freezing it?

Or were some of the involved components non inverted? If yes, then when uninverted and inverted matter interacts, what decides if the uninverted matter acts normal or inverted? To create an inverted fire, do I need inverted wood and inverted lighter and be inverted by myself? Or can I ignite non inverted wood with an inverted lighter (and myself also uninverted) creating an inverted fire that freezes me? In case of inverted bullets (and the buildung explosion) uninverted matter seems to act inverted when hit by inverted weapons. How far does that go? If I lay a row of overlapping lying dominos and the last (first) one is inverted, do then all the non inverted dominos "stand up" up to the first inverted one?

Comment: I have a sneaky suspicion you've just recently watched *Tenet*...

Comment: @CaptainJamesT.Kirk it all just sounds like that one episode of Red Dwarf to me.

Comment: I think you'll find that nothing about this movie makes sense and thinking about it more only makes it worse.

Comment: The car isn't inverted (it didn't go through the booth), and he's warned in dialog about driving a non-inverted car before this scene. We see the fire go "forward" in scene time, so the fire must be inverted and thus the non-inverted car freezes. But if the lighter was inverted, it should have only made the non-inverted gas colder, not ignite it. My conclusion is that the scene is gibberish.

Comment: @Harabeck - We don't know if the car went through the turnstile offscreen at some point (I guess if it did, from the perspective of non-inverted people this would have had to be *after* the Tenet people got control of the turnstile from Sator's people). I think it probably makes more sense to assume it did, given the way the Protagonist initially sees it get damaged in reverse when it crashes, before he gets inverted and drives it. But the idea that an inverted person in an inverted car set on fire with an inverted lighter getting colder *from their own perspective* doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I think the car must be inverted. Because from non inverted view we saw the accident in reverse. Or is it enough to have an inverted person drive (and crash) an uninverted car, to  make that car uncrash from ininverted view? BTW I can't imagine, how it should work if the car is uninverted. From uninverted POV the inverted driver must have entered id, set the gear to backwards and drive it backwards all along. I assumed the warning about driving was for the same reasons explanined earlier. Headwind comes from backward making it's compensation while driving weird.

Comment: That the car must be inverted after the Tenet people got control over the turnstile is an interesting point. But it makes completly sense. Why should Sator place a second inverted car he does not need? It was placed there "later" by the Tenet people to preserver the timeline and for exactly the reason that the protagonist can (could have) use(d) it.

Comment: But it begs the question, where Sators inverted car did come from. :-) Maybe also from the Tenet people? But than, shouldn't Sator wonder?